# What's the VB.Net equivalent of a VB6 RecordSet?

Tags: database, vb.net, vb6

I am new to vb.net and i'm trying to convert an old vb6 project to vb.net.i am using access as database. 
The form has 3 combo boxes-
1.bustype (cmbbustype)
    
 2.bus no (cmdbusno)
    
 3.route no(cmbrtnum)

text boxes - 9 :- 
1.beginning stop (txtbegstop)
 2.end stop (txtenstop)
 3.start from (txtsfrom)
 4.end to (txtendto)

5.number of children (txtchild)

6.number of adults (txtnoadult)

7.half ticket price (txthalf)

8.full ticket price (txtfull)

9.total fare (txttotal)

It uses the command button-"rate" to calculate the total fare of children and adult

```
 Private Sub cmdrate_Click()
Set rs = con.Execute("select Childfare,Adultfare from busdetails where Start='" + Txtsfrom.Text + "' and send='" + Txtendto.Text + "'  ")
If (Not rs.EOF) Then
    Txthalf.Text = rs(0)
    Txtfull.Text = rs(1)
    c = Val(Txtchild.Text) * Val(Txthalf.Text)
    a = Val(Txtnoadult.Text) * Val(Txtfull.Text)
   Txttotal.Text = c + a

Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Input", vbCritical, "E-Ticketing"
End If
rs.Close
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
connectdb

Set rs = con.Execute("select Bustype from busdetails")
While (Not rs.EOF)
    Cmbbustype.AddItem rs(0)
     rs.MoveNext

Wend
rs.Close

Set rs = con.Execute("select Mincharge fhrom busdetails where Bustype='" + Cmbbustype + "' ")
If (Not rs.EOF) Then
    Lblmin.Caption = rs(2)
End If
rs.Close

Set rs = con.Execute("select Busnumber from busdetails")
While (Not rs.EOF)
Cmdbusnumber.AddItem rs(0)
rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close

Set rs = con.Execute("select RtNo from route")
While (Not rs.EOF)
    cmbRtNum.AddItem rs(0)
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
rs.Close
End Sub


Please help me to convert this code to vb.net! i am really stuck.
```

how to use record set in vb.net?

Comment: Could you add some detail on what issue you're having? An error? Or something not working?

Comment: You want us to convert the whole code? Not too likely to happen. SO expects you to do most of the work and come here to ask specific problems. In any case, bear in mind that converting VB6 to VB.NET is quite easy: just paste the VB6 code in a new VB.NET project and fix the problems (Visual Studio will help you on this front). Additionally, note that VB.NET supports quite a few VB6 in-built functionalities.

Comment: i want the form to calculate the rate of adult and child fare by using the details in other forms and the combo boxes to display columns from different tables.

Comment: i tried pasting it in vb.net but i don't know if it uses a record set or not!

Comment: What version of VB.Net are you using ?      VB 2008 was, I believe, the last one that could directly convert VB6 projects to .NET.  Subsequent versions wont do that ( wont open a VB classic project ), but will point out syntax problems within code when found ( leaving you with a copy/paste method of getting your classic code into a .net project ).

Comment: Link for the VB6 upgrader. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zc22a8x(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using 2010, a direct ( automated ) conversion wont be available.  I suggest you try to download a copy of 2008 Express and use that to carry out the automated portion of the conversion.  It will convert what it can, and render a report that identifies each bit of non-conformant coding that remains, which you must then address manually.  Much of this will end up being one of these 2 things :   1) all variables must be of a defined type ( no more VARIANT types ),  2) all variables must be initialized to a value before being referenced ( no default values assigned ).

See also :    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14w905kc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure that recommending an old VS (and thus .NET) version is a good idea. Much less a restricted format as Express (which will soon disappear on account of the new Community free versions). Also your clarifications are not too accurate: firstly, the VB.NET equivalent to Variant is Object (although Object variables behave differently than Variant ones and setting the proper types is recommendable); secondly, variables do usually need to be initialised (not the case with all the types though; for example: Enums) but not assigned with a default value (the initialisation does it).

Comment: Additionally and as explained in my comment above, VB.NET is still quite similar to VB6 (and accepts many VB6 methods). Relying on old VB6 syntax in a new VB.NET project doesn't sound too recommendable. On the other hand, automatic conversions are rarely the ideal alternative. For example: most of the posted code can be directly used in VB.NET (although some parts might be converted to newer .NET alternatives). That's why I think that a manual conversion is the best option (and the best way to learn the new language). In any case, moving back to VS 2008 doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well, perhaps it was not as clear as I thought it was, but the idea of moving back to 2008 was to gain the available advantages of automated conversion because I am not making the assumption that the code displayed is nearly the whole set of code.  So, the 2008 version is just ONE step in a series, followed by the OP's current .NET environment and of course the manual polishing that usually goes along with converting legacy to .NET.   And then there are 3rd party tools, but they cost money, and 2008 Express does not.

Comment: Your idea was very clear. Perhaps my comments weren't: an automatic conversion is rarely the ideal solution; much less in this context, where both languages are quite similar (and converting manually might be an excellent training to get used to the new format). Also bear in mind that the Express VB.NET is not the same one than in standard Visual Studio. Now (since 2013, I think), there are Community versions (= free Visual Studio similar to the standard one) and thus converting to Express doesn't seem recommendable. Hope that my points are clearer now. Sorry, but I have to go.